# Using EGOTableViewPullRefresh together with KKGridView

Tags: iphone, gridview, refresh

Has anyone one ever tried that ? EGOTableViewPullRefresh seems rely on the fact that the parent view is a UITableViewController, but KKGridView is essentially a UIViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually KKGridView is a UIScrollView, if you are using `KKGridView` by subclassing `KKGridViewController` you can make this work by setting the gridView's delegate to self.

```
if (_refreshHeaderView == nil) {

        EGORefreshTableHeaderView *view = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.gridView.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.gridView.bounds.size.height)];

        self.gridView.delegate = self;

        view.delegate = self;
        [self.gridView addSubview:view];
        _refreshHeaderView = view;
        [view release];

    }
```